# Validate urls with anchor hashbangs in python

Tags: python, validation, url, urllib, urlopen

I'd like to check if a url with section anchors using the # operator (example: `http://url_link.html#section`) is valid in Python.

I'm using `urlopen` to check as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def is_valid_url(url):
    try:
        r = urlopen(url)
        return r.status == 200
    catch Exception e:
        return False
```

But calling `is_valid_url` with invalid section anchors doesn't return `False`

```
is_valid_url("http://valid_url_link.html#valid_section") # True
is_valid_url("http://valid_url_link.html#invalid_section") # Also True!
```

Is there a way to detect that `http://valid_url_link.html#invalid_section` is not a valid url in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) function to check if the url has fragment attribute equal to '`invalid_section`'.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>>
>>> result = urllib.parse.urlparse("http://valid_url_link.html#invalid_section")
>>> result.fragment == "invalid_section"
True
>>> result = urllib.parse.urlparse("http://valid_url_link.html")
>>> result.fragment == "invalid_section"
False
```

So you can modify your function to something like this.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def is_valid_url(url: str) -> bool:
    try:
        return (urlparse(url).fragment != "invalid_section") and (
            urlopen(url).status == 200
        )
    except Exception:
        return False
```

Comment: I still get `True` in both cases. I get `result.fragment = 'invalid_section'` and calling bool on that string returns `True`

Comment: Thanks, but Now it gives `False` even for valid sections. It gives `True` only if I give a url without any section suffixes

Comment: @locke14 My Bad. I have edited my answer again to check against only `invalid_section`

Comment: I can't hardcode "invalid_section" in the fuction as there might be multiple invalid sections that the function might not be aware of. `urlparse(url).fragment` gives the section part of the url as a string irrespective of whether it is valid or not.